# Scrolling dynamic website using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scroll down the website by using webdriver in Mozilla however the code is not working.

That is the code I have written:

from selenium import webdriver
import time

```
`
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/forums/c/sell-on-amazon")
browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,3000)","")
time.sleep(15)
browser.close()`
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `execute_script()` method to scroll down the page, the second argument should be None instead of an empty string.

Try :

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/forums/c/sell-on-amazon")
browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,3000)")
time.sleep(15)
browser.close()
```